# string builder apending URLs and Variables

Tags: c#, winforms, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a properly formed URL using variables with the string builder:

```
strB.AppendLine("<a href='http://www.facebook.com/' + col1 + ">" + ""Link</a>");
```

But what am I doing wrong? Please can you help me fix it?

`col` is where i store my value for the Facebook username.

I thought it was obvious? But the problem is that i get a badly formatted URL.

Comment: Looking at the syntax highlighting in your question should tell you what's wrong!

Comment: 5 down votes? and all i wanted was a fresh pair of eyes, as ive been on this for hours. Im not asking for much! Yet get down votes!!!!!!

Comment: You got downvotes because you just said "I'm doing it wrong", rather than saying what error you got. -5 is a bit excessive though.

Comment: I just realized the typo i made. I was meant to ask, `what am i doing wrong?`

Comment: That's fine, but you should still explain what made you think you're doing it wrong. You're getting an error, right? Always post the error.

Comment: That line of code doesn't compile. Either your real code is different, or you don't get an URL at all because you can't run your program.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`StringBuilder.AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
strB.AppendFormat("<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/{0}\">Link</a>", col1);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter actually, because this is html content. But we can simply append a `\n`

Comment: It might be HTML, but it also might be a list of fragments, intended to be newline separated. OP didn't say what he was doing.

Comment: true, but instead of newline I think `<br>` tag is more appropriate in this case :)

Comment: why would it be newline fragments when the example clearly is the username / user profile for FB?

Answer (score -1):

```
strB.AppendLine("<a href='http://www.facebook.com/" + col1 + "'>Link</a>");
// you have quotes in wrong places                 ^
```

Comment: What is the reason of downvotes?

Comment: I think it was your typo. Fixed it for you :)

Comment: Oops and I messed up your arrows. I'll let you fix it so I don't clobber your answer.

Comment: See `'` ......... col1 should move into `' '`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy  Here is the correct code `strB.AppendLine("<a href='http://www.facebook.com/" + col1 + "'>Link</a>");`

Comment: @L.B yep, already fixed single quote

Comment: But with a so simple question. You are either correct or not.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Do you think it is the same? One of them forms an invalid html but the other is ignored by html renderer( at most a simple space)

Comment: @L.B which one forms invalid html?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy your answer in previous edit. What is so hard to accept? you posted a bad and incorrect answer (unexpected from a 70K rep), and still have a +22. You should thank to people instead of complaining.

Comment: @L.B reputation does not affect typos. Have a good night, downvoter :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you too :)